# Events Tickets Plus with WooCommerce - creating event gives 405

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am unable to add a new event to or edit an event on my site when I have Event Tickets, Event Tickets Plus, Events Calendar and Woocommerce enabled. These are the only plugins I currently have enabled.

I have had this issue since I installed Events Calendar Pro on my site on Sunday. I have deactivated and deleted Events Calendar Pro multiple times but I am still unable to create an event “post”… first I was receiving server response time and memory errors and now when I add an event with a ticket it is giving me a 405. It does seem to create the post/event as well as product items in WooCommerce but without the crucial information I have provided – i.e. the Start and End time and will not post the event to the Calendar. Trying to edit and update these produces a 405. When I try to go to one of these supposedly created event pages I receive a 404.

I've posted in their support forum, but have yet to get a response. I am wondering if anyone else has had a similar issue with this plugin? How did you solve it? Does this sound like a problem with the WordPress install? I am rather new to the more complicated sides of Wordpress. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.